# Display a jsondata from database in flutter

Tags: sql-server, flutter, dart, mss

so i have a method called `cetak()` like this

```
var res = "";

  Future<void> cetak(String query) async {
    var req = await SqlConn.readData(query);
    var parsedJson = jsonDecode(req);
    setState(() {
      res = parsedJson[0]['CUST_KELO'];
    });
  }
```

and im using `cetak()` method like this

```
cetak("SPS_SALEMISA_7 'MW','FB','11'")
```

the table in my database have so many column, and i want to display some of them, for example i want to display `CUST_KELO` column.

but when i want to display res in `Text()` widget, nothing is show, the code is

```
Text(res),
```

but in my debugConsole (im using VScode),

**E/flutter ( 4539): ..."CUST_KELO":115, "CLXX_DEFA":1, "AREA_COMP":03, "WAXX_NMBR":6285852517258}]**

and `CUST_KELO` value on debugconsole is same like in the database/

any idea how to display `CUST_KELO` Column in `Text()` widget

Answer (score 0):

Check if `setState()` is called for the same widget that has text. Maybe you rebuild the parent but child is const Stateless widget.